# Novel similar to Rendezvous with Rama but I do not think it's this one

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember reading it in the 90s.

The main story happens on an alien spaceship where human explorers find a relic.

I can't remember exactly what it was but what I do remember is that it offered great technological advancement but the characters were worried it might be a trap created to find and eliminate intelligent lifeforms.

An other big point was that the habitants of this world were all connected via a social media/virtual reality.

Finally, this one might be a red herring so if this particular point doesn't fit, please post your answer, I think the author was Canadian.

Comment: You say the story is set on an "alien spaceship" but then you say "habitants of this world were all connected via a social media/virtual reality". How are the "spaceship" and the "world" related?

Answer (score 4):

While the description is vague this could be Robert Reed's [Marrow](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/100208.Marrow)

All the action takes place on an alien spaceship, The Great Ship. They find a relic, what actually appears to be a small planet hidden within the ship, and they worry it could be a trap of some sort.

> The Ship has traveled the universe for longer than any of the near-immortal crew can recall, its true purpose and origins unknown. It is larger than many planets, housing thousands of alien races and just as many secrets.
>
> Now one of those secrets has been discovered: at the center of the Ship is . . . a planet. Marrow. But when a team of the Ship's best and brightest are sent down to investigate, will they return with the origins of the Ship--or will they bring doom to everyone on board?

Robert Reed is American not Canadian.
And it was first published in 2000, later than the '90s estimate.